# Is it grammatically correct to attributively use nominative forms of nouns in New Latin?

Tags: adjective, new-latin, noun, genitive, case

There are some muscle names in New Latin that seem to be nouns as far as I can tell, such as *flexor* and *extensor*. However, according to several Wikipedia articles for these muscles, they behave as if they are attributive nouns with a nominative form. For example, in the name *musculus extensor digitorum*, the *digitorum* part seems fine to me because it's in the genitive; but the *extensor* part seems weird because it just gets tacked on to *musculus* even though it looks like a nominative form, and from what I've heard you're not supposed to just string nominative forms of nouns together in Latin.

So, are phrases like *musculus extensor digitorum* grammatically correct in proper New Latin?

Answer (score 10):

It's valid even in Classical Latin, in fact!

Generally, it's fine to put two nouns together in the nominative (or, rather, in the same case) when one of them gives the general category of a thing and the other gives the name of a specific instance. For example, Caesar often talks about *provincia Gallia*, and Cicero uses constructions like *C. Gallus senator*.

This seems to be the same construction: it's a *musculus* named the *extensor digitorum*. In fact, I can't think of any other construction that would be appropriate here: there's no obvious way to derive an adjective from *extensor*, and the genitive makes one subordinate to the other, which is odd when they're two separate descriptions of the same object.

Comment: Such actor nouns are common epithets if that counts: e.g. *Mars ultor*.

Comment: Are you certain that *provincia Gallia* is similar enough to *musculus extensor*? To cite a parallel in German, in the phrase *Bundesrepublik Deutschland*, *Deutschland* is a nominative form placed after *Republik*, but *Bundes* is a genitive form placed before (and the genitive case doesn't denote possession here, just a way to used nouns attributively in German). Maybe it's possible that proper names aren't exactly "attributive", *Gallia* doesn't exactly "modify" *provincia*.

Comment: An English parallel would be something like *the noun phrase 'noun phrase'*, in which *noun* is attributive to *phrase* and placed before it, but *'noun phrase'* is not attributive, but some kind of "name", and is placed after.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw The key is that both nouns refer to the same entity. The place is both _provincia_ and _Gallia_. The person is both _Gallus_ and _senator_. The muscle is both _musculus_ and _extensor_. (Joonas's example: the god is both _Mars_ and _ultor_.)

Comment: Here's the thing about these examples, they don't seem generalized enough to draw a definitive conclusion from. All these contain proper names, and from what I've seen in Romance and Germanic languages, proper names in noun phrases don't function quite the same as attributive nouns and often have some distinct constructions for themselves like those I cited above. Could you find an example that only contains common nouns for a more convincing comparison?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw See Allen and Greenough 282 for more examples. Names seem relevant here, imo, because you're asking about the name of a piece of anatomy.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw E.g. from A&G: *omen equos vidi* (Aen. 3.537): "I saw an omen of four horses." No proper name there.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to Cerberus's answer, an "attributive noun" is not the same thing as an appositive noun/apposition. Latin has apposition; it does not have attributive nouns.

An attributive noun would be a noun used like *muscle* in the English phrase *muscle pain,* which refers to pain of a type that is associated with muscles. You can't use the nominative form *musculus* in that way.

The usage in *musculus extensor digitorum* is different because the *extensor digitorum* is a muscle, it isn't just something associated with muscle(s).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Draconis's good examples, for linguistic reference, this is normally called **[apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)**:

> **Apposition** is a grammatical construction in which two elements, normally noun phrases, are placed side by side and so one element identifies the other in a different way. The two elements are said to be in apposition, and one of the elements is called the **appositive**...